# How to collapse concealed text?

Tags: vim, folding

The problem is as follows:

1. This is about a plain `.txt` file
2. I have enabled the conceal feature and created this syntax file:

   ```
   set conceallevel=3
   syn region cTest conceal start='€£' end='£€'
   hi cTest ctermfg=DarkYellow
   ```
3. I write first a summary/skeleton of what I want to say, and put it in between €£ and £€. Then, in the same line, I write a lengthier text following the guidelines of the summary. The whole file contains many (>100) lines.
4. The conceal feature works very nicely, except for one point: if the ensuing lines are each, e.g., 600 characters long (summary 120, text 480), and if the screen is 80 characters wide, the lines the cursor is not on will display 6 screen lines plus… a void corresponding to the hidden 120 characters.

Is it possible to collapse this void (if I may say so)?

(I could not find any tutorial on the conceal feature except the Tip #1308, and the "conceal" tag is not accepted by Stack Overflow...)

Comment: Could you give me more information? Are you trying to hide a whole line, or just the additional void part at the end of a long line? If you're work is all on the same line then Heptite is correct, but if you conceal a whole line, then you could use custom folds.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, currently there is no way to eliminate this void created by the conceal feature; apparently the development of the conceal feature was very complicated and involved some compromises to get it "out the door" in time for the 7.3 release.

This may be fixed in a future release if someone submits a working patch to Bram Moolenaar and/or the Vim developers mailing list.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Frustrating, but not disappointing. Conceal is a great feature. We shall wait.