# Don't wrap certain lines

Tags: vim

I'm using conceal in a plugin to hide some data, but when the hidden line gets too long it makes a wrap which is still hidden and just looks weird.

how it looks:

```
<hidden metadata line that the user can't see......
which is wrapped and makes 2 empty looking lines when it gets long>
stuff
```

how it should look:

```
<a very long metadata line that is not wrapped>
stuff
```

How can I tell vim to not wrap certain lines (concealed ones)?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3897656/

Comment: That isn't a duplicate, that person isn't concealing entire lines I believe, but is working on one/two large lines. That post is very insightful though, and I hope conceal gets the attention it deserves with Bram.

Answer (score 0):

Wait, I figured out 1 way. Custom folding. A single line fold won't show as wrapped.

Now I just have to write a custom syntax folding part for my plugin and I'm golden.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to do it on current version.

```
This is intentional.  Without this cursor movements would be messed up,
as the screen line depends on how text is concealed, which requires
syntax parsing, which is slow.
```

[For more information, see this discussion on vim_dev group.](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!searchin/vim_dev/conceal/vim_dev/ZQTXsL4Tdyg/BfivYWpXj9AJ)